# Adding Makers To Google Maps V3 When No Data Connection

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am in a situation where, even if there are no maps being displayed due to no connection (the screen is just blank with not features available), I still want to add the markers and polylines onto the Google Map.

Is this possible?

It seems that if there is no data and no maps have been loaded that nothing is displayed?

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Answer (score 0):

This issue is described here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5017

There seems to be a workaround of not using ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

They will probably fix it completly in the next release.